# Missing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
try:
    import json, time, os, re, io
    from PIL import Image
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    import requests, base58
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except:
    print('ERROR:: missing module(s)')
    exit()
```

This is the script, I installed BeautifulSoup,requests,pillow and base58 and i'm getting `ERROR:: missing module(s)`

Comment: Have you tried `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`? Also, temporarily remove the `try` `except` block(which isn't doing anything useful) to see exactly which modules are missing, what's the ouput?

Comment: Technically, you don't know that you are catching an `ImportError` at all. Only catch exceptions that you know how to handle; otherwise, let them bubble up and exit the interpreter if necessary.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use a bare `except` statement to hide the exception and print a vague, likely unrelated, error message.

Comment: run the file without try catch. what error do you get?

Comment: Well, from what you've shown us, it's working exactly like it's supposed to! My suggestion would be to open a shell and try each of these import statements individually. If it fails, look through the application's docs to learn how to properly import. It's usually the first thing they show you how to do.

Comment: I removed the `try` `expect` block and now this is ther ERROR im getting File "C:\Users\Bamba\Desktop\AssetReaper\main.py", line 17
    settings = json.loads(open('./settings/settings', 'r').read())